# Camel Test - assertMockEndpointsSatisfied with File contents

Tags: xml, unit-testing, apache-camel

I have a test running to verify that the XML that reaches an endpoint is the same as the XML contained in a file. I'm running `assertMockEndpointsSatisfied()` and have verified that the XML is identical using another tool.

```
String sourceXml = readFile("src/test/resources/source1.xml");
String targetXml = readFile("src/test/resources/target1.xml");

// Mock WS endpoint should receive one message
mockResult.expectedMessageCount(1);
// Target endpoint should receive the target XML
mockResult.expectedBodiesReceived(targetXml);
// Start the process by sending in the Source XML
start.sendBody(sourceXml);
// Run all assertions
assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
```

and the failure (modified elements and namespaces) is reading:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://jmsamq:queue:SettlementOut Body of message: 0. Expected: <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<api:req xmlns="testNS" xmlns:api="testAPI">
    <api:test>
        <a>0600017121</a>
        <b>01</b>
        <c>1000.50</c>
        <d>2000</d>
    </api:test>
</api:req>
> but was: <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<api:req xmlns="testNS" xmlns:api="testAPI">
    <api:test>
        <a>0600017121</a>
        <b>01</b>
        <c>1000.50</c>
        <d>2000</d>
    </api:test>
</api:req>
>
```

I've considered XMLUnit but would rather not have to do this. When I compare to a string instead of a file using '\n    ' instead of a new line and 4 spaces, it works fine.

Comment: When I use the marshal property filterNonXmlChars = "true", my test passes. There must be some character hidden in there but I can't figure out what it is..

Comment: I'll just use XMLUnit for now. It works fine, but I'd rather find a way to use the assertMockEndpointsSatisfied() check instead.

Answer (score 0):

The built in functionality you're using compares the XML exactly as opposed to by its logical content. I had to write my own wrapper that used XMLUnit, which I'd offer but my previous employer owns it now. :(

Comment: Yeah I don't know why it isn't comparing successfully though. The console shows 2 identical strings and says they aren't the same :) I have got it running using xmlunit and will stick with that for now.